# Storing a task id for each celery task in database

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I have using celery with `MySQL`. I want to to store the task id as a plain integer in a database or in a variable of celery `task`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not create a celery task model, and save a celery task id to that model?

```
class CeleryModel(models.Model):
    celery_task_id = models.CharField(max_length = 50, unique=True)
```

Then:

```
def some_celery_task():
    result = celery_task.delay()
    celery_task = CeleryModel(celery_task_id = result.id)
    celery_task.save() # added save line
```

Your integer value would then be: `celery_task.id` to correspond with the actual, unique celery_task_id.

UPDATE: another way ...

First `python manage.py inspectdb > inspectdb.py`. Inside that file you will find:

```
class CeleryTaskmeta(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    task_id = models.CharField(max_length=765, unique=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    result = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date_done = models.DateTimeField()
    traceback = models.TextField(blank=True)
    hidden = models.IntegerField()
    meta = models.TextField(blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'celery_taskmeta'
```

Next, `python manage.py startapp celery_model`. Put this file in the models.py file. I use south, so my final step would be `python manage.py convert_app celery_model`. However, its unnecessary. Now you have django level access to this celery datatable, and can read the primary key for each task as your integer value. E.g

```
>>> ct = CeleryTaskmeta.objects.get(id=1)
>>> for k,v in ct.__dict__.items(): print k,v
... 
status SUCCESS
task_id 2fa95f24-7640-434c-9fef-0732ac1d23c7
date_done 2013-02-17 19:22:56+00:00
traceback None
_state <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x10263fa90>
meta eJxrYKotZAzlSM7IzEkpSs0rZIotZC7WAwBREgb9
result gAJLBC4=
hidden 0
id 1
```

Someone clever would know how to make your `CeleryTaskmeta` a read-only model because I don't think you would want to tamper with the datatable.

UPDATE: to the last part of your question:

```
>>> from celerytest.tasks import add
>>> result = add.delay()
>>> result.int_id = 1
>>> for k,v in result.__dict__.items(): print k,v
...
parent None
app <Celery default:0x10264df10>
task_name celerytest.tasks.add
int_id 1
id 01503afd-d196-47af-8e10-e7dc06603cfc
backend <djcelery.backends.database.DatabaseBackend object at 0x1026842d0>
```

Comment: Thank you for thorough and clean explanation!

Comment: Bro the problem is I want to retrieve the task_id as the process starts. It turns out data are written in CeleryTaskMeta table only after the job successfully completes.

Comment: @Cole how do you store results from an asynchronous scrape in the database?

Answer (score 1):

To get the celery task ID when the task is started I do the following:

```
process_task = my_task.apply_async(args=[args])
task_id = process_task.task_id
```

where my_task is a method within tasks.py